# Automatically update cells

Tags: excel, vba, automatic-properties

I currently have this code for my worksheet:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' ensure events are always enabled when we exit this Sub, even if we have an error
    On Error GoTo errExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim SpotRate As Double
    SpotRate = Me.Range("H2").Value

    If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Range("E3").Value = Target.Value * SpotRate
        Else
            Range("E3").ClearContents
        End If
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Range("C3").Value = Target.Value / SpotRate
        Else
            Range("C3").ClearContents
        End If
    End If

errExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

There is a pair a dropdown in cell C2 that contains information for the spot rate.

When I input the values into C3 or E3 the code works as required. However, if I change the value in cell C2 (which changes the spot rate in H2), these values don't automatically update in C3 or E3. Is there a way I can change this so that the value in C3 is held constant but E3 is automatically updated according to the new spot rate? Thanks.

Comment: Any particular reason for not using a standard Excel formula?

Comment: Well if you change H2 you will Exit the function without triggering any conditional code-blocks (the ones inside If) - hence you don't change anything. If you want to have E3 change when you change H2 you have to tell the code to do that. (Probably with an `Or` operation in you condition

Comment: Is there a way to be able to enter information, while still having a formula in there (without overriding the formula)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, v, SpotRate As Double
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling single-cell changes
     
    On Error GoTo errExit
    
    SpotRate = Me.Range("H2").Value
    
    Select Case Target.Address(False, False)
        Case "C2"
            'trigger updates via event handler
            Me.Range("C3").Value = Me.Range("C3").Value
            Me.Range("E3").Value = Me.Range("E3").Value
        Case "C3"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Range("E3").Value = Target.Value * SpotRate
            Else
                Range("E3").ClearContents
            End If
        Case "E3"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Range("C3").Value = Target.Value / SpotRate
            Else
                Range("C3").ClearContents
            End If
    End Select
        
errExit:
    If Err.number <> 0 Then Debug.Print Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: No luck, thanks though

Comment: Works for me (at least as far as I understand your description of what you want).  FYI "no luck" is not very useful in telling us what happened/didn't happen when you tried it.

Comment: Cell E3 doesn't change when cell C2 is changed (C2 is a dropdown list not sure if this changes anything)

Comment: Does C2 have a Data Validation dropdown, or are you using some kind of forms/ActiveX control?  Exactly how is H2 linked to C2?

Comment: It's a Data Validation dropdown

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Does the code run when you change the drop-down?

Comment: The code runs fully, just nothing changes in E3

Comment: Can you tell us (1) what values are in the C2 drop-down? (2) Exactly how is H2 linked to C2?

Comment: I'm unable to tell you the content specifically of C2 but it is made up of two correlated pairs using _ _ _ - _ _ _  , but H2 is linked by using the left & right functions to find the first and second components... when these components change H2 then changes (as it uses a dependent formula on C2)

Comment: C3 and E3 are dependent on each other's value, so what happens when C2 is changed will depend on whether the change event is triggered for C3 first, or for E3.  You will need to add more rules if you want some more-specific outcome when C2 is changed.

Comment: H2 depends on C2, then C3 and E3 depends on H2...note: C3 and E3 are both values that the user inputs. If a value is input into C3 then E3 outputs C3 * H2, but if a value is input into E3 then C3 outputs E3/H2

Comment: But if H2 changes (as C2 is changed) then it should affect both cells, but *exactly* how should that work?  Let's say H2 is 10 and you'd entered 5 into C3, auto-updating E3 to 50.  If H2 then changes to 20, what should the new values of C3 and E3 be?

Comment: I would want C3 to remain the same at 5, then E3 to update to 100 (sorry I am being vague I just can't reveal too much as it's a project)

Comment: In that case comment out the line `Me.Range("E3").Value = Me.Range("E3").Value`

Comment: Still doesn't work... E3 stays the same when H2 changes

Comment: Working for me - here's a copy https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kDeaiw5SdKHDM4WW60DNctDp4H2DM8In/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106591725375141807281&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

You have blocks of code that perform some actions when the Target (range that changed, triggering the Worksheet_Change event) address is "$C$3" and "$E$3".

```
If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then

ElseIf Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
```

You need an equivalent block that will perform the calculation if Target.Address = "$H$2".

Assuming my understanding of what you're trying to achieve is correct, this should work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' ensure events are always enabled when we exit this Sub, even if we have an error
On Error GoTo errExit
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim SpotRate As Double
SpotRate = Me.Range("H2").Value

'if H2 is not a number
If Not IsNumeric(SpotRate) Then
    Range("E3").ClearContents
    Range("C3").ClearContents
    Exit Sub
End If

'E3 changed
If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then
    'adjust E3
    If IsNumeric(Range("E3").Value) Then
        Range("E3").Value = Target.Value * SpotRate
    Else
        Range("E3").ClearContents
    End If
    
'C3 changed
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
    'adjust C3
    If IsNumeric(Me.Range("C3").Value) Then
        Range("C3").Value = Target.Value / SpotRate
    Else
        Range("C3").ClearContents
    End If
    
'C2 changed
ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    If IsNumeric(Me.Range("C2").Value) Then
        'adjust E3
        If IsNumeric(Range("E3").Value) Then
            Range("E3").Value = Target.Value * SpotRate
        Else
            Range("E3").ClearContents
        End If
        'adjust C3
        If IsNumeric(Me.Range("C3").Value) Then
            Range("C3").Value = Target.Value / SpotRate
        Else
            Range("C3").ClearContents
        End If
    Else
        'C2 is not a number
        Range("E3").ClearContents
        Range("C3").ClearContents
    End If
End If

errExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

EDIT: Sorry, misuderstood the question at first, corrected my comment to include the right solution.

Comment: I have tried adding
```
    ElseIf Target.Address = "$C$2" Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Range("E3").Value = Me.Range("C2").Value * SpotRate
    Else
        Range("E3").ClearContents
    End If
    End If
```
but this still doesn't work. Does it matter that cell C2 is a dropdown list?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question at frist, I corrected the code in the comment above, could you try it now?

Comment: Still not working... thank you anyways